# Size of .apk is increasing with the increase with target devices (LDPI,MDPI,HDPI,X-Large Screens)

Tags: android, file, filesize

i have a developed an app targeting MDPI devices initially which is having many images and the size of the app is nearly 16MB.

Now i need to target all the other device Screens.For this the images need to be replicated to Target these devices. Which increased the .apk to 45MB to 50MB.

1. My question over here is this file size acceptable for market place?
2. Or can i generate different .apk's for each target device and place it market place. so that based on device the downloading corresponding .apk will be downloaded?

Please some one help out of this .. i have searched a lot on this and came to be futile ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the max size for an apk is 50mb. To get around this, apps with heavy resources (i.e. games) implement downloading of resources to the sdcard. You may want to look into something like this, and at that point you'd download the resources for that particular device and not every resource for all the different screens.

Answer (score 1):

Sakshi,

You can use the [`<supports-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#attrs) element in your `AndroidManifest.xml` to target devices with specific screen sizes.  You can use this to create an APK that will only show up on the market for devices that have a screen size compatible.  You will have to have a different package name for each package as well, and this will greatly complicate your build process.

Comment: Hi thank you is there anyway that i can reduce the .apk size. As i know the images are responsible for my increase in size ?